# Is my router part of the Internet backbone

Tags: routing, router, internet

Is my router routing packets other than the ones coming from/to my local network, or is my router only getting my specific packets and the router infrastructure of the ISPs are the ones handling general routing?

Comment: Another simple way too look at it is your router is effectively an access layer device....and routing usually takes place in the core layer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Internet routers communicate with each other using routing protocols to learn the shortest path from one network to another network. Unless your router is in the path from one network to another network, it will not see packets between the two networks.

Obviously, your router is in the path of packets destined to your network, but unless you are configured as a transit between two different ASes (usually a misconfiguration if you have your own AS and multiple ISPs), your router should not see packets destined to any other network.

Answer (score 0):

Your router can route  and become back bone router for  internet traffic only when your router is deployed in path of internet traffic .